# Differences between ScriptManager and ClientScript when used to execute JS?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can somebody explain for me what the differences are between ScriptManager and ClientScript?

ClientScript works well when I use it in Button_Clicked event, but it doesn't work when I use it in the GridView_RowUpdated of a GridView. (The GirdView is wrapped inside an update panel). Then I tried ClientScript and it worked perfectly in this case.

Comment: Did you mean to say "Then I tried 'ScriptManager' and it worked perfectly in this case." ?..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You've pretty much identified the primary difference. The ScriptManager is meant to be used with async postbacks, which is why it works with the UpdatePanel. The ClientScript class is for synchronous postbacks. So, if you're going to be posting back from an UpdatePanel, be sure to use the ScriptManager instead of ClientScript.

[ScriptManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.aspx)

Comment: " So, if you're going to be posting back from an UpdatePanel, be sure to use the ScriptManager instead of ClientScript. " I use ClientScript and it works perfectly, the script manager didn't work in this case

Answer (score 3):

<sub>9 years after this question was asked, I'm finding myself doing some *software archeology* and I'm writing up my own notes about ASP.NET's idioms, hence this answer, which I hope *actually* answers the question, as I felt ShellyFM's answer was incorrect, as this statement: "ClientScript class is for synchronous postbacks" is untrue)</sub>

---

### `ClientScriptManager`

- The [`Page.ClientScript` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page.clientscript?view=netframework-4.8) exposes an instance of [`ClientScriptManager`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager?view=netframework-4.8).

  - Each `Page` instance has its own single instance of `ClientScriptManager`.
  - `ClientScriptManager` stores a list of `<script>` elements. These `<script>` elements are automatically rendered inside the `<asp:form runat="server">` element, located immediately after where ViewState controls are rendered in `<div class="aspNetHidden">`.
- These `<script>` elements can be registered using different methods:

  1. `RegisterClientScriptBlock`
  2. `RegisterClientScriptInclude`
  3. `RegisterClientScriptResource`

  - For example:

    - `RegisterClientScriptBlock` adds an inline script directly to the page.

      ```
      // Page code:
      this.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock( type: typeof(TestPage), key: " Script1", script: "function foo(){}", addScriptTags: true );
      ```

      ```
      // *.aspx code:
      <form id="form1" runat="server">
      </form>
      ```

      ```
      // Rendered result:
      <form method="post" action="./TestPage.aspx" id="form1">
      <div class="aspNetHidden"><!-- ViewState is rendered here --></div>
      <script type="text/javascript">function foo(){}</script>
      </form>
      ```
    - `RegisterClientScriptInclude` will add a `<script src=""></script>` element without any inline script:
    - `RegisterClientScriptResource` will add a `<script>` that gets its content from an `<EmbeddedResource>` from a .NET Assembly's `GetManifestResourceStream`. The script is referenced using `src="/WebResource.axd?d=..."` instead of being rendered inline.

      - The `/WebResource.axd` file doesn't exist in your filesystem. It's a reserved URL pattern that ASP.NET handles by itself by-default.
  - The `Page.BeginFormRender` method directly calls `ClientScriptManager.RenderClientScriptBlocks()` and passes it the `HtmlTextWriter`, so `ClientScriptManager` *is not* a WebControl.
- Somewhat surprisingly, `ClientScriptManager` does not offer a way to *remove* or un-register a script - nor can you enumerate existing registrations: [you can only replace an existing registration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14337214/how-to-unregister-page-clientscript-in-c-sharp-asp-net) - and only if you know the `String key` that was used to register it in the first place.

### `ScriptManager`

- The `ScriptManager` class was added in [*ASP.NET AJAX*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_AJAX) which was an extension to ASP.NET 2.0 released in 2007.

  - It was built-in to ASP.NET in ASP.NET 4.0 in 2010 (instead of being an extension).
  - It lives in `System.Web.Extensions.dll` (in both ASP.NET 2.0 and 4.0), while `ClientScriptManager` lives in `System.Web.dll`, which indicates it's more central and integral to ASP.NET than `ScriptManager`.
  - `ScriptManager` itself *is a WebControl* (it derives from `System.Web.UI.Control`) so it's responsible for rendering HTML directly via its `.Render()` method, whereas `ClientScriptManager` was invoked directly by `Page`'s `BeginFormRender`.
- The `ScriptManager` **does not** have any instance methods for registering `<script>` elements to render to the page.

  - It does have `static` methods for registering scripts to a `Page` instance, but all it does is call into `Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock`, `Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude`, or `Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptResource`.
- The `<asp:ScriptManager>` control *must* be placed inside your `<asp:Form>` and [must be placed before any other WebControls that depend on `ScriptManager`-registered scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13473808/the-scriptmanager-must-appear-before-any-controls-that-need-it). You also cannot have more than 1 `<asp:ScriptManager>` control on a page.
- So if `ScriptManager` simply *wraps* `ClientScriptManager`, what does it actually *do* itself?

  - Well, unlike `ClientScriptManager`, the `ScriptManager` *does* let you remove a script registration and get a list of current registrations.

    - ...provided those scripts were registered with `ScriptManger` and not `ClientScriptManager` *and* that you removed the offending script *before* `ScriptManager.RegisterScripts()` is called (which happens inside `Page`'s `PreRender` event btw).
  - Additionally, `ScriptManager` handles the automatic creation of JavaScript code for ASMX and WCF client proxies and renders those as registered scripts too.

    - This is what the `<asp:ScriptManager><Services>` collection is for. For each `<asp:ServiceReference />` child element it will generate a `<script>` containing functions that wrap `XMLHttpRequest` calls to each `[WebMethod]` method.

      - `[WebMethod]` methods exist in `.asmx` classes, though your `WebService` subclass also needs `[ScriptService]` applied.
      - `[WebMethod]` can also be `static` methods on your `Page` subclass, though you need to set `EnablePageMethods="true"` to use those.

## TL;DR:

- `ClientScriptManager` is integral to ASP.NET WebForms and renders pre-registered `<script>` elements inside your `<form>`.
- `ScriptManager` is an optional extension to ASP.NET WebForms (as a part of *ASP.NET AJAX*) and essentially *extends* `ClientScriptManager` to allow for removing registrations and also generates JavaScript to make it easier to call `[WebMethod]` methods defined in `.asmx`  `WebService` or a "Page method" (which is a `static` method on a `Page` subclass, also with `[WebMethod]`).

Comment: This is better than the official documentation, thank you for putting in the effort. 

You didn't mention anything about the RegisterStartupScript function, which according to the docs is just like RegisterClientScriptBlock except it's placed right before the ending </form> tag instead of after the initial <form>. Have you found anything else regarding RegisterStartupScript? Also maybe worth mentioning is that although you can only have 1 declaration of ScriptManager you can use [ScriptManagerProxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.scriptmanagerproxy)