# The ScriptManager must appear before any controls that need it

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have created a new ASP.NET Web Application, and after debugging i got Server Error

> The control with ID 'WaitingPopup1' requires a ScriptManager on the page. The ScriptManager must appear before any controls that need it.

I'm new with ASP.NET so where schould i install my ScriptManager, in the web.config?

Comment: Just place <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" id="somethi" /> above popup control

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The `ScriptManager` is a control that needs to be added to the page you have created.

Take a look at this [Sample AJAX Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398890(v=vs.100).aspx).

```
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        ...
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: you need 1 script manager per form. so if you have a master page you can place the script manager in its form and all of your pages will benefit form it.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using microsoft ajax on your page you need [the script manager control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398863%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) added to your master page or the page that needs it. It Manages ASP.NET Ajax script libraries and script files, partial-page rendering, and client proxy class generation for Web and application services

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManger1" runat="Server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

The [full usage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
<asp:ScriptManager
    AllowCustomErrorsRedirect="True|False"
    AsyncPostBackErrorMessage="string"
    AsyncPostBackTimeout="integer"
    AuthenticationService-Path="uri"
    EnablePageMethods="True|False"
    EnablePartialRendering="True|False"
    EnableScriptGlobalization="True|False"
    EnableScriptLocalization="True|False"
    EnableTheming="True|False"
    EnableViewState="True|False"
    ID="string"
    LoadScriptsBeforeUI="True|False"
    OnAsyncPostBackError="AsyncPostBackError event handler"
    OnDataBinding="DataBinding event handler"
    OnDisposed="Disposed event handler"
    OnInit="Init event handler"
    OnLoad="Load event handler"
    OnPreRender="PreRender event handler"
    OnResolveScriptReference="ResolveScriptReference event handler"
    OnUnload="Unload event handler"
    ProfileService-LoadProperties="string"
    ProfileService-Path="uri"
    RoleService-LoadRoles="True|False"
    RoleService-Path="uri"
    runat="server"
    ScriptMode="Auto|Inherit|Debug|Release"
    ScriptPath="string"
    SkinID="string"
    SupportsPartialRendering="True|False"
    Visible="True|False">
        <AuthenticationService
            Path="uri" />
        <ProfileService
            LoadProperties="string"
            Path="uri" />
        <RoleService
            LoadRoles="True|False"
            Path="uri" />
        <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference
                Assembly="string"
                IgnoreScriptPath="True|False"
                Name="string"
                NotifyScriptLoaded="True|False"
                Path="string"
                ResourceUICultures="string"
                ScriptMode="Auto|Debug|Inherit|Release" />
        </Scripts>
        <Services>
            <asp:ServiceReference
                InlineScript="True|False"
                Path="string" />
        </Services>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Comment: If not use ***microsoft ajax***, not use `asp:ScriptManager` ? Alternative to **ScriptManager** _without_ use ***microsoft ajax*** ?

Answer (score 6):

You can add your Script Manager tags just below the `<Form>` tag of your page. Here is how you can place your Script Manager tag.

```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
```

If you are using Master Pages, its recommended to use your Script Manager in  your Master page so that you do not have to write it again and again on every page that contains AJAX controls.

Comment: I have **MasterPage**, but not use ***AJAX controls***, only _jquery_. Do I need `asp:ScriptManager` ?

Answer (score 4):

Just put `ScriptManager` inside `form` tag like this:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
```

If it has `Master Page` then Put this in the Master Page itself.

Answer (score 2):

The [`ScriptManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398863%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is a web control that you register in the page using

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManger1" runat="Server" />
```

inside the Form tag

Answer (score 2):

There many cases where script Manager may give problem like that. you Try This First add Script Manager in appropriate Placeholder or any place Holder which appears before the content in which Ajax Control is used.

1. We need to add ScriptManager while using any AJAX Control not only update Panel.
   `<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManger1" runat="Server" />`
2. If you are using Latest Ajax Control Toolkit (I am not sure about version 4.0 or 4.5) you need to use that Particular ToolkitScriptManager and not ScriptManager from default Ajax Extensions.
3. You can use only one ScriptManager or ToolKitScriptManager on page, If you have added it on Master Page you no need to add it again on Web Page.
4. The problem mentioned here may because of ContentPlaceHolder Please Check how many content place holders you have on your master page. Lets take an example if you have 2 content Placeholders "Head" and "ContentPlaceHolder1" on Master Page and ContentPlaceHolder1 is your Content Page.please check below code I added here my ScriptManager on Second Placeholder just below there is update panel.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="MainContent" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManger1" runat="Server" />
          <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Most of us make mistake while designing web form when we choose masterpage by default on web page there are equal number of placeholders as of MasterPage.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master Pages/Home.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="frmCompanyLogin.aspx.cs" Inherits="Authentication_frmCompanyLogin" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
```

We no need to remove any PlaceHolder it is guiding structure but you must have to add the web form Contents in Same PlaceHolder where you added your ScriptManager(on Master Page) or add Script Manager in appropriate Placeholder or any place Holder which appears before the content in which Ajax Control is used.

Answer (score 1):

It simply wants the ASP control on your ASPX page.  I usually place mine right under the  tag, or inside first Content area in the master's body (if your using a master page)

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManager" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <div>
            [Content]
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

On the ASP.NET page, inside the form tags.

Answer (score 0):

The script manager must be put onto the page before it is used. This would be directly on the page itself, or alternatively, if you are using them, on the Master Page.

The markup would be;

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" LoadScriptsBeforeUI="true"
            EnablePartialRendering="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

- with a `head` tag with `runat="server"`
- inside a `form` tag with `runat="server"`
- before the `ContentPanels` that contain controls that require it - typical controls with `UpdatePanels`:

<%=PageTitle%>

```
</form>
 </body>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
```

Add above code after  tag.
It worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).