# How to get ScriptManager to work with ScriptmanagerProxy

Tags: c#, asp.net, scriptmanager

I have been dealing with an unusual set of errors when I try to compile my asp.net page. This page is inheriting from my masterpage. It should be getting the Scriptmanager from there. But the errors I am getting suggest that it is not.

Now I have this in my page:

```
    <%@ Page Title="MassUpdate" Language="C#"
         MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master"
         AutoEventWireup="true"
         CodeBehind="Update.aspx.cs"
         Inherits="AdminSite.Update"
         MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" %>


     <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server" >

        <div id="contentarea">
            <div>
                <h3 style="color:Red; padding-left:5px;">
                    WARNING - This page can push large amounts of data into the database. Use care when using it!
                </h3>
            </div>    


        <asp:ScriptManagerProxy runat="server"  >

        </asp:ScriptManagerProxy>
```

And in my masterpage, I have this:

```
<body>
    <header>
       <div id="banner">

            <h1 style="color:#DBFFFF">UAC Parts Admin</h1>    
    </div>
</header>
<form id="form1" runat="server">

<div id="container">

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">


    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
        <LoggedInTemplate>
      <div id="menubar">

        <h6>Reports</h6>
        <div>
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
                <Scripts>
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery.js" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jqueryui.js" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/menubar.js" />
                </Scripts>
            </asp:ScriptManager>
```

The  first error is this:

> The control with ID '' requires a ScriptManager on the page. The ScriptManager must appear before any controls that need it.

It happens when I don't have ScriptManager on my page and use ScriptManagerProxy instead.Even though I have ScriptManager on my Master page.

Now when I put a ScriptManager on my page I get a different error.

> Only one instance of a ScriptManager can be added to the page.

What do I need to do to get this to work?
Is this an issue with one of my Nuget Packages? (JuiceUI,Widgmo, etc)

I would be glad to post code if requested.

**EDIT:**
Yeah, this whole thing has been weird. Oddly the master page did not have issues itself. But only when the other pages used it did I have any problems. Moving it to the first element after the form tag was the solution I believe. Though I had also moved the ScriptManagerProxy up a bit in my code too.

Comment: Can you post the markup containing the `ScriptManager` on your master page, and the `ScriptManagerProxy` on your .aspx page?

Comment: Certainly I will do that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The ScriptManager must appear before any controls that need it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13473808/the-scriptmanager-must-appear-before-any-controls-that-need-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ScriptManager` must appear before any `ContentPlaceHolders`. Generally as Joshua pointed out, the script manager is put at the first element after the form tag. Like so:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jqueryui.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/menubar.js" />
        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManager>

    <div id="container">

        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">


        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
</form>
```

The reason for this is because the .aspx pages that uses this master page provide content that is placed into the `ContentPlaceHolder` controls. Because your `ContentPlaceHolder` appeared before your `ScriptManager`, the `ScriptManagerProxy` located in your content page was throwing because the `ScriptManager` would not be defined until later down the page.

This can be a bit odd to think about because you are defining controls in multiple different places. But the codebehind does not execute until everything is put together.

Comment: Thank you. That was definitely the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Put the ScriptManager on masterpage and ScriptManagerProxy on the .aspx page.

Answer (score 2):

you need to put the script manager near your form declaration in Master page;

have a look on this Also: [Walkthrough: Creating an Ajax-Enabled Web Site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386580%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        ...
    </form>
</body>
```

For Your Second Question:[ScriptManager Control Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398863.aspx)

```
Only one instance of the ScriptManager control can be added to the page.
The page can include the control directly, or indirectly inside a nested
component such as a user control, content page for a master page, or nested
 master page. If a page already contains a ScriptManager control, but a nested
or parent component needs additional features of the ScriptManager control, the
component can include a   ScriptManagerProxy control.
For example, the ScriptManagerProxy control enables you to add scripts and 
services that are specific to nested components.
```

you either have to remove your script manager from master page if wanted to use in Content page or Use proxy in content page with in-addition of script manager in master page