# Bind data for an Object Data source in code behind and remove SelectMethod

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, code-behind, objectdatasource

I need to prevent objectdatasource from auloading data and managing that in the code behind .
when I remove the SelectMethod  , the following problem occurs

> The Select operation is not supported by ObjectDataSource 'DataSource' unless the SelectMethod is specified.

this is my objectDataSource

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="DataSource"  runat="server" TypeName="declaration_prod_liste"  
      EnablePaging="true" StartRowIndexParameterName="startrows"
      MaximumRowsParameterName="pagesize"
      SelectCountMethod="GetDataSourceCount">
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Comment: You could just not use ObjectDataSource, it's really just a convenience object. Or, you could add a control/session/etc parameter to it and make sure that parameter makes it return no data.

Answer (score 1):

You could set/change the `SelectMethod` of objectdatasource in an appropriate event in code-behind. For example, in code below this is being done in Page_Load event.
But, you need to specify its SelectMethod in html code and then just cancel it in `Selecting event` as shown in second code-snippet.

I am assuming your objectdata source id is `DataSource1`.

Also, make sure you specify your SelectMethod in hmtl for objectdatasource.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   DataSource1.SelectMethod = "SelectMethod";
   GridView1.DataSourceID = DataSource1.ID ;
   GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

You could cancel objectdatasource autopouplating by canceling in the `Selecting event` as in code snippet below. Make sure to subscribe to this event in objectdatasource html.

```
protected void ObjectDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, ObjectDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    //puty your logic when to cancel and when not to cancel
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Html should look like below.

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="DataSource1"  runat="server" TypeName="declaration_prod_liste"  
      EnablePaging="true" StartRowIndexParameterName="startrows"
      MaximumRowsParameterName="pagesize"
      SelectCountMethod="GetDataSourceCount"
      SelectMethod="SomeMethod"
      OnSelecting ="ObjectDataSource1_Selecting" >
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Comment: the real problem which leads me to think of this is in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47180999/listview-databind-causes-lost-of-formview-data ; up to now still blocked

Comment: So what exactly is the issue on your end?