# confirm Box after the Data table gets data from sql

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net

```
 function alertbox() {
    var mode = document.getElementById('<%= hdnMode.ClientID %>').value;
    if (mode == "EDIT")
        return false;

    if (confirm("the same data is present against that ID ?") == true) {
        document.getElementById('<%= hdnYesNo.ClientID %>').value = "COPY";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('<%= hdnYesNo.ClientID %>').value = "CANCEL";
    }
 }
```

the above confirm message should appear after the retrieve data from sql and

> ```
> Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"CallMyFunction",
> "MyFunction()",true);
> ```

how to use it from codebehind and if so then how to get the return value based on the value 
copy and cancel

Comment: Do you use ScriptManager ? One thing that you can try is initialize the `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript`

Comment: yes ,i need a return value from ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript is that possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to provide an example that I just created as a testing application.

Firstly, I used the ScriptManager to apply all the javascript files that I like to be present for the web page as follows:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>        
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
            <Scripts>
                <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/JS/tester.js" />
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>                
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" 
                    Text="Call database" />                
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

In the `<Scripts>` tag add more of your JS files. This will ensure that your javascript file is added when you load the webpage.

The code that is there in my tester.js is:

```
function alertbox(data) {
    alert("Completed the database operation with following data = " + data);
}
```

Now coming to your code behind scenario, what I have in my sample data is, I created a button on the webpage that would do some database operations and once completed it will alert the user about the sql update.

The button event handler is as follows:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Thread.Sleep(2000);
     int sqlReturnValue = ExecuteTheQuery();
     ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "Database Completed", "alertbox(" + sqlReturnValue  + ");", true);
}
```

Now this will call the Javascript function alertbox.

(Note: this is just a small example of how you can achieve the thing that you expect)

**Update**:

The same can be achieved with ClientScript as well. 
What I did is, add a script tag:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <script src="JS/tester.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

In the code behind of the button click:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Database Completed", "alertbox(23);", true);
}
```

For understanding ClientScript and ScriptManager, check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049041/differences-between-scriptmanager-and-clientscript-when-used-to-execute-js).