# Close popup window after inserting to database

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a popup window that closes when a <kbd>Cancel</kbd> button is clicked:

```
btnCancel.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.close();");
```

but I want to use another button (Save) to insert to database, then close the window:

```
if( success )
{
closePopup();
}
```

The insert function will be in C#, not in JavaScript.

Comment: Where is your code for opening a popup?

Comment: open code must be in the parent page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "onclick", "window.close()", true);
```

Comment: thanks alot it works now !                                             your code 'ScriptManager' that works perfect with UpdatePanel.      Ref. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7054225/1328869

Answer (score 1):

`window.close()` will close the current window. If you want to close the opened window popup try following the below approach.

Assuming you are opening a popup with a reference like below (Parent.aspx)

```
var windowObjectReference;
var strWindowFeatures = "menubar=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes";

function openRequestedPopup() {
  windowObjectReference = window.open("mypage", "Popup Page", strWindowFeatures);
}
```

For closing a popup (child.aspx)

```
 btnCancel.Attributes.Add("onclick", "parent.closePopup();");
```

Then (parent.aspx)

```
function closePopup()
{
 windowObjectReference.close();
}
```

Refer [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open) and [`window.close()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.close)

Comment: sorry, insert function will be C# code, not javaScript

Comment: @DevBassem, you need to call like `parent.ClosePopup()`. Check the updated answer