# How to register client script in HttpHandler to execute javascript function?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, httphandler

I have an `html` page that using ajax to call `HttpHandler` which needs to return `javascript` function back to client, so, when button is clicked this function gets executed.

I'm learning `ajax` now and using old fashion way to call it.

Here is my `.html` file:

```
<script language="javascript">
    var XMLHttpRequestObject = false;

    try {
        XMLHttpRequestObject = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (exception1) {
        try {
            XMLHttpRequestObject = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.MLHTTP");
        }
        catch (exception2) {
            XMLHttpRequestObject = false;
        }
    }

    if (!XMLHttpRequestObject && window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        XMLHttpRequestObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }

    function getData(dataSource) {
        if (XMLHttpRequestObject) {
            XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET", dataSource);

            XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = function () {
               if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 
                    && XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200)  {
                        eval(XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText);
               }
            }
            XMLHttpRequestObject.send(null);
        }
    }

    function alerter() {
        var targetDiv = document.getElementById("targetDiv");
        targetDiv.innerHTML = "Got the JavaScript OK.";
    }

</script>
</head>
 <body>
    <h1>Returning JavaScript</h1>
  <form>
      <input type="button" value="Fetch JavaScript" onclick="getData('http://myserver/DataSources/data.ashx')" />
  </form>
  <div id="targetDiv">
      <p>The fetched data will go here.</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Than I have my `HttpHandler` where I need to register client script to call the function:

```
public class data1 : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        EchoMessage(context);   
    }

    private void EchoMessage(HttpContext context)
    {

    }
 }
```

What should I write in my EchoMessage to register the script needed to run on a client side?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use RegisterStartupScript or RegisterClientScriptBlock to declare a script on the server and pass it on to be executed on the client. These are static functions of ClientScript and ScriptManager.

[Differences between ScriptManager and ClientScript when used to execute JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049041/differences-between-scriptmanager-and-clientscript-when-used-to-execute-js)

[Difference between RegisterStartupScript and RegisterClientScriptBlock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666519/difference-between-registerstartupscript-and-registerclientscriptblock)

Comment: In HttpHandler I do not have an access to these methods.

Comment: I can use ScriptManager

Comment: Yes you could use ScriptManager instead. Wasn't sure which one would be available.

Comment: My javascript function should be returned in `XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText`

Comment: I'm not sure is this is the right solution, but I used the following and it worked: `context.Response.Write("alerter()")`

Answer (score 0):

After all, I just decided to go with `context.Response.Write("alerter()")` and it seems to be working. Not sure if this is the right solution though

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the **ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript**, which worked for me as below:

```
Page page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, this.GetType(), "ErrorSave", "$cmsj('.alert-label').html('Maximum 4 quick links are allowed.');", true);
```