# Alert not working in UpdatePanel VB.Net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, alert

Here is what I have tried.

ASPX File:

```
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">

            <ContentTemplate>
                 <asp:Button OnClick="btnOK1_Click" ID="btnOK1" runat="server" Text="Save" />
            </ContentTemplate>

        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

ASPX.VB:

```
        Protected Sub btnOK1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
            Dim alertMsg As String
            Dim alertScript As String
            alertMsg = String.Format("You Selected {0}", "My Message")
            alertScript = String.Format("<script type= text/javascript>alert('{0}');</script>", alertMsg)
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.[GetType](), "Alert", alertScript)
        End Sub
```

I tried to get an alert box with a message when clicked a button (Save) from backend. I tried with the solutions from the StackOverflow. But, the codes does not work for me to get an javascript alert box. The event triggers fine and runs through the code. Anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to lie with the fact that you are using `ClientScript` rather than `ScriptManager`.

`ClientScript` is used for Synchronous postbacks, whereas `ScriptManager` for Asycronous.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049041/differences-between-scriptmanager-and-clientscript-when-used-to-execute-js) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

```
replace your code with these

Protected Sub btnOK1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim alertMsg As String
    Dim alertScript As String
    alertMsg = String.Format("You Selected {0}", "My Message")
    alertScript = String.Format("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('{0}');</script>", alertMsg)
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType, "Alert", alertScript, False)

End Sub
```